# WDS server corrupt

Tags: wds

After about 30 days of operation, the WDS deployment is corrupted. This has happened twice in completely different systeminstallations, albeit using the same installation-media.

Windows Server 2022 Standard

The WDS service does not start, and when running "wdsutil /uninitialize-server" I get the error, same error with /initialize-server:

0x7E The spcified module could not be found

Deep in the Eventlog, the Deployment-Services logs shows various errors. This one mentions the error code I get when I try to start the service:

[WDSSERVER][WDSDCMGR] initialization failed (rc=126)

And a bunch of error pointing to .cpp files.

The plugin to MMC is represented by a folder icon instead of the WDS-logo.

Just tried to remove the WDS feature, and reinstalled it. No changes.

In ADSIEdit, I have given the account "Write all properties" to the -Remote-Installation object located under the -object, since I am not allowed to use Domain Admins on my member server due to security reasons.

Why would a WDS-deployment all of a sudden become corrupt? There has been 0 interactive logins to the server, and it is completely offline, so no accidental Windows Updates has been applied.

I dont want to reinstall the server

Comment: What happens if you remove the WDS role and add it back? (To have the WinSxS files refresh the live installation). There are a plethora of reasons your system could become corrupt. The first thing I would do is install the latest updates, there are known issues with not installing updates. I would also migrate off of WDS as it is slowly being killed for other more modern tech. Also, according to Microsoft's own design guidelines, it is a best practice to reimage in a lot of troubleshooting cases. Also best practices is to not treat servers as pets and treat them as reimageable cattle instead.

Comment: I did try to remove the WDS, but nothing changed, same unstartable service. We are in the middle of development, and my access to a WSUS is not done. I am creating new OpenStack-images of a pretty modern/patched 2022 from MS. Will have to try that when its moved through the hoops from Online to Offline :) Thanks. Also, need to check out whats new in the Winblows deployment tools sphere. Thanks! I do treat most of my servers as cattle, however, the Windows deployment is much more fragile than my Linux side. Windows really wants to be a pet. With lots of petting.

Comment: Take a peek at WIMboot, you can use your Linux environment to WDS style boot into Windows, it also has a few other benefits such as booting from image indexes that are not one. https://ipxe.org/wimboot that might allow you to standardize and work around this issue. I am a huge fan of Windows myself and with a heavy heart recommend this to you.

Comment: Sounds like a case for Microsoft support

Comment: What is the underlying hardware and operating system platform?

Comment: Underlying hardware is a mix of Dell and HP. On these we run Openstack. And in one tenant we have a couple Windows VMs in a domain, where one machine houses WDS and DHCP. I can redeploy and get a working domain for a month, with ability to produce workstations. Until I check in again a few weeks later, to redeploy or deploy new ones. And I am stuck with this self-corrupted crap. Its been repeated once. And now I rescued the situation by dropping the WDS-VM, cleaning the AD up and reinstalling from OS images.

Comment: @ElliotHuffman We do use some variant of ipxe to get our Linux workstations running and managed by Foreman. We have some blue prints of ideas to get this working for Windows workstations as well. If this WDS-thing doesn't get resolved, we might have to hurry up and innovate a bit :) And I am sorry for you, having to recommend WIMBoot. I have lost my love, after having to automate a full domain deployment. Windows is not very "bright" and does not suit automation, at all. :) Just the fact that Powershell puts "already exists" in stderr. I mean, thats rc=0 and nothing else :)

Comment: I second @Turdie, I think you need to file a unified/premier support ticket. It shouldn't break like the way you are describing. Worst case is to migrate your PXE stack to Linux using the WimBoot. Although ideally you would migrate all management systems to Intune and skip PXE reimaging and just use cloud-based reimaging. Peek at OSD Cloud if you need to wipe partitions. I haven't personally used PXE/WDS in ~5 years at this point due to cloud maturity. PXE can lead to threat actors being able to gain access to your environments if you don't spend a lot of time securing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreate the remote install folder

```
wdsutil /initialize-server /reminst:{RemoteInstallFolder}   (example: WDSUTIL /Initialize-Server /RemInst:D:\RemoteInstall)
```

And make sure your logged on with a domain account and not a local admin account for example.

Comment: wdsutil runs, and show the help without any flags, /initialize or /uninitialize just gives med 0x7E, unable to load module or something worded similarly.

Comment: We have a domain tiering regarding access in place. We dont allow domain admin outside the domain controllers. However, our domain/server-admins has the approriate permissions to the sub-object on the WDS computeroobject, being able to write the properties needed using the wdutil-commands, when its not corrupted.

Comment: Unable to load module is generally a DLL corruption of some sort

Comment: Kudos to you all to have credential partitioning implemented, that is kind of rare to see